# NoMethodError in browser but work in Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a newbie for RoR 3, i have followed instruction from Simple Rails 2 book. I got NoMethodError in browser but when i tried from Console, it works without any error. Can any one help me ?

My full Code can view at Github : https://github.com/iamkevinhuang/shovel/

Error in Browser :
[image]

Work in Console : 
[image]

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Please put [action show](https://github.com/iamkevinhuang/shovel/blame/master/app/controllers/stories_controller.rb#L33-L35) out site protected block. Example put it in line 11